# Enumerate lines while printing to to file .CSV PYTHON

Tags: python, list, csv

I have a simple list of lists.  4 lists each with 3 values in each

```
with open('test2.csv', 'w',) as f2:
 f = csv.writer(f2, delimiter= '\t')
 header = ["SENSOR", "h1", "h2", "h3"]
 f.writerow(header)
 for idx, lists in final_list:

        f.writerow(lists)
        print "IDX:",idx, "LISTS:", lists
```

errors occur with "for idx, lists in final_list:" and it says:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Comment: how do you determine the sensor number?

Comment: provide what you have done and sample input of final_list

Comment: Why do you think you are using `enumerate()` wrong?

Comment: @AnandSKumar the sensor number isn't specific to any list of data, BUT each line will be data for a unique sensor, the data I'm printing out could be 4 sensors and thus 4 lines, or 12......16.....10000000.

Comment: @IanAuld it expects a sequence, whereas I tried to enumerate a list of lists.

Comment: `for idx, val in [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]...]` will work just fine. How were you using it?

Comment: @IanAuld I tried >for x, y in final_list:......too many values to unpack apparently.  Maybe I am putting the parameter into .writerow() improperly?

Comment: Please update your question to show what you actually tried

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83327/discussion-between-cc6g11-and-ianauld).

Answer (score 1):

You were not far :-) you just need :

```
for idx, lists in enumerate(final_list):
    f.writerow(lists)
    print "IDX:",idx, "LISTS:", lists
```

Comment: so were you ;) ...f.writerow([idx] + lists) is required

Comment: @cc6g11 I didn't know what you wanted to do with `idx`, I just gave it to you :-)